# onOnClientClick is working but onClick is not working on asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick, onclientclick

I have this code on my javascript:

```
         function getListOfPOI() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById('tbCity').value;

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var request = {
                        location: results[0].geometry.location,
                        radius: 8000,
                        types: all //['store']
                    };
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
```

And I call this function with the button below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddCity" Height="20px" Text="Add" runat="server" OnClientClick="return getListOfPOI();" OnClick="btnAddCity_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"    />
```

The OnClientClick is perfectly works, but the OnClick function is not fired. What should I do? Thank you in advance for your insights.

Cheers,
Nisa

Comment: could you post your html code? is your button located inside an update panel or any other partial-page-rendering oriented controls? im not sure but is it possible that your javascript code is failing and true is not returned ? i also see that you have a textbox with id 'tbCity', if this is an asp:textbox control then your code will not work because asp changes the id on client side, so you have to retrieve the new clientside id using compiler directive <%=tbCity.ClientID%>

Comment: My button is located on the page, not inside a panel or anything. My Javascript is fine, because it worked as I wanted it. The only problem  is it didn't fire my "btnAddCity_Click" function on the server side. Do you know how to make the onClick works?

Comment: The btnAddcity_click function, did you write it yourself or is it generated by visual studio? There might be a linking issue or  incorrect variables in the function, when u double click the button in designer view does it focus on the function in the code behind or creates a new emoty one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of @lucidgold, finally it is now working! The solution is to call the javascript function on the button server side. After tweaking around, here's the complete solution:

1. I remove return true on the JavaScript function
2. Remove the useSubmitBehaviour property on the button:
   `<asp:Button ID="TestButton" Text="Test Me" OnClick="TestButton_Click" runat="server"/>`
3. Run RegisterStartupScript in C# as follows:
    `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "script", "<script type ='text/javascript'> getListOfPOI(); </script>");`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fire JavaScript Code + Server code is to do the following where we make use of ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript and call our JavaScript function!

**In your .ASPX Page:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function clientTestClick() {
            document.write("Test!");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="TestButton" Text="Test Me" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="TestButton_Click" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Depending on code behind language..

**C#:**

```
protected void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "JavaScript", "clientTestClick();", true);

    /*  PUT YOUR SERVER CODE HERE */
}
```

**VB.NET:**

```
Protected Sub TestButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TestButton.Click

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "JavaScript", "clientTestClick()",True)

    Dim x As String 
    x="hello" 'You can set a debug-point here and see that this will fire

End Sub
```

Hope this helps, let me know!

Comment: Hi @lucidgold, thank you for taking the time. I tweaked a bit your answer and now it is working! Below answer is the solution.

Comment: I am glad I can help, could you mark my answer as helpfull, so other can re-use. Thanks!